# How we can use model objects in ModelSerializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have to create an endpoint to make a customer subscribes to a chef.
The subscription model has two FK fields chef and customer.

model/subscriptionSerializer:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    chef = models.ForeignKey(Chef, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="chef")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="customer")
```

I created this serializer:

```
class SubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    chef = serializers.SerializerMethodField("get_chef")
    customer = serializers.SerializerMethodField("get_customer")
       
    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        fields = [
            "id",
            "chef",
            "customer",
        ]
    
    def get_chef(self, *args):
        return Chef.objects.get(pk=self.context.get("chef"))
    
    def get_customer(self, *args):
        return User.objects.get(pk=self.context.get("customer"))
```

I want to have one endpoint like this: `customer/chef/<int:chef_id>/subscribe`

So in view.py I used `ModelViewSet`:

```
class CustomerSubscribeChefView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = SubscriptionSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(CustomerSubscribeChefView, self).get_serializer_context()
        context.update({"chef": self.kwargs['chef_id']})
        context.update({"customer": self.request.user.id})
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.subscription_set

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        return Response(
            {"msg": "Chef is subscribed!"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        )

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        self.perform_destroy(instance)
        return Response({"msg": "Chef is unsubscribed!"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

when I try to send a post request I got this error:
`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: core subscription. chef _id`

I've tried to use my custom serializer so I've updated `SubscriptionSerializer` to be like this:

```
class SubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    chef = ChefListSerializer
    customer = CustomerSerializer
       
    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        fields = [
            "id",
            "chef",
            "customer",
        ]
```

But I don't know how to serialize chef and customer objects.

What is the problem with my approach, and how I can fix this?

**Update**
I changed the subscription serializer to be like this

```
class SubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    chef = Chef()
    customer = User()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = kwargs.pop('context')
        self.chef = Chef.objects.get(pk=context.get("chef"))
        self.customer = User.objects.get(pk=context.get("customer"))
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        fields = ["id", "chef", "customer"]
```

But I still get the same error.

Comment: print your serializer on create method and see once what data has arrived

Comment: `chef = ChefListSerializer(many=True)`. Do the same for the customer.